# Perl tr replace but ignore first 2 characters

Tags: perl, tr

I need convert
`$foo= 101100` to `10aabb`

Currently using this but it replaces entire string

`$foo =~ tr/10/ab/;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's some Perl magic for you:

```
my $foo = 101100;
substr($foo, 2) =~ tr/10/ab/;
print $foo;
```

Output:

```
10aabb
```

Basically we take the substring of the string, starting at the 2nd character offset, and transliterate it.

In the [documentation for substr](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr) you can read about this:

> You can use the substr function as an lvalue, in which case EXPR must itself be an lvalue.
>
> ...
> When used as an lvalue, specifying a substring that is entirely outside the string raises an exception. Here's an example showing the behavior for boundary cases:

```
my $name = 'fred';
substr($name, 4) = 'dy';         # $name is now 'freddy'
my $null = substr $name, 6, 2;   # returns "" (no warning)
my $oops = substr $name, 7;      # returns undef, with warning
substr($name, 7) = 'gap';        # raises an exception
```